# How do I switch from immediate mode to VBO

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo, point-clouds

I'm doing point cloud with color images and corresponding depth maps. I have successfully done this using immediate mode (glBegin/glEnd) but then I drew a second point in space it lagged horribly when I turn and move the view using mouse and arrow keys.

So my question is how do I switch this code from immediate mode to VBO, which is said to be able to boost performance.

Code:
First point cloud object

```
    float** imgdata;
    imgdata = new float*[320];
    for(int a=0; a<320; a++)
    {
        *(imgdata + a) = new float[240];
    }

    float*** texture;
    texture = new float**[320];
    for(int a=0; a<320; a++)
    {
        *(texture + a) = new float*[240];
        for(int b=0; b<240; b++)
            *(*(texture + a) + b) = new float[3];
    }

    GBmp bm0;
    GBmp bm1;
    bm0.load("depth-use1.bmp");
    bm1.load("color-use1.bmp");

    for (int j=0; j<bm0.h; j++)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<bm0.w; i++)
        {
            texture[i][j][0] = bm1.rgb[i*3+j*bm0.w*3];
            texture[i][j][1] = bm1.rgb[i*3+j*bm0.w*3+1];
            texture[i][j][2] = bm1.rgb[i*3+j*bm0.w*3+2];
        }
    }

    for (int j=0; j<bm0.h; j++)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<bm0.w; i++)
        {
            imgdata[i][j] = bm0.rgb[i*3+j*bm0.w*3];
        }
    }   

    float x, y, z;
    glPointSize (6);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for (int j=0; j<bm0.h; j++)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<bm0.w; i++)
            {
                x = i-160;
                y = j-120;
                z = imgdata[i][j];
                glColor3f(texture[i][j][0]/255, texture[i][j][1]/255, texture[i][j][2]/255);
                if (imgdata[i][j] != 0)
                glVertex3f(x,y,z);    
            }
        }
    glEnd();
```

Second point cloud object

```
    float** imgdata1;
    imgdata1 = new float*[320];
    for(int a=0; a<320; a++)
    {
        *(imgdata1 + a) = new float[240];
    }

    float*** texture1;
    texture1 = new float**[320];
    for(int a=0; a<320; a++)
    {
        *(texture1 + a) = new float*[240];
        for(int b=0; b<240; b++)
            *(*(texture1 + a) + b) = new float[3];
    }

    GBmp bm2;
    GBmp bm3;
    bm2.load("depth-use2.bmp");
    bm3.load("color-use2.bmp");

    for (int j=0; j<bm0.h; j++)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<bm0.w; i++)
        {
            texture1[i][j][0] = bm3.rgb[i*3+j*bm0.w*3];
            texture1[i][j][1] = bm3.rgb[i*3+j*bm0.w*3+1];
            texture1[i][j][2] = bm3.rgb[i*3+j*bm0.w*3+2];
        }
    }

    for (int j=0; j<bm0.h; j++)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<bm0.w; i++)
        {
            imgdata1[i][j] = bm2.rgb[i*3+j*bm0.w*3];
        }
    }
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(36,0,1,0); 
    glPointSize (6);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);  
     float x1, y1, z1;
     for (int j=0; j<bm0.h; j++)
         {
             for (int i=0; i<bm0.w; i++)
             {
                 x1 = i-210;
                 y1 = j-120;
                 z1 = imgdata1[i][j];
                 glColor3f(texture1[i][j][0]/255, texture1[i][j][1]/255, texture1[i][j][2]/255);
                 if (imgdata1[i][j] != 0)   
                 glVertex3f(x1,y1,z1);
             }
         } 
     glEnd();
```

Comment: Is that all rendering code? Called on every frame? If that's the case, you're recreating arrays and reloading textures on every frame. VBO wouldn't help you.

Comment: yeah those are all in my display()...are you saying I should create another function outside of display() to hold the arrays?

Comment: Don't you think that recreating the same array and reloading the same bitmaps from disk is.. slow and pointless, to put it lightly? It could be done once at loading stage.

Comment: @SodaGuns: `new` and `delete` are very expensive operations. Also the result of their use there is an invariant. Also you're already naming the result `texture`. Don't you think, that using a *real* OpenGL texture would be far better?

Comment: then is it possible to make those arrays global?